# RTCP enabled or Disabled - RR and RS in SDP

Tags: sip, sdp

1) Can some one tell me that , if RR and RS lines are not present in SDP - then it is considered as RTCP enabled or disbaled

2) RR and RS lines present in SDP then its consider as RTCP is enabled . Just give me the brief about it

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such correlation.

- It is very normal to have RTCP without RR and RS lines in the SDP
- If you see RR and RS lines in the SDP that usually means that the endpoint is RTCP capable (but nothing guarantees that you will actually receive RTCP packets on the other side. Those might have not sent at all for various reasons, or not forwarded by media relays or blocked by firewalls/NAT's)

Answer (score 0):

if you don't see RR and RS values in SDP. In this case default values are generally taken.

- for that case usually RTCP bandwidth is 5% of total RTP bandwidth.
- Also 25% of RTCP is reserved, so that new senders can join the rtp session
- RS will get 1.25% and RR will be 3.75% of total in default.